# How to dynamically generate the URI of a service in Camel

Tags: json, apache-camel

I'm fairly new to Camel and I'm trying to build a Camel route that reads a file. One of the fields of the file is a date, and that date will be used to call a service with a JSON request.

Example of harcoded call:

```
.inOut("cxfrs:https://myserver.edu/dostuff/20180115/deals");
```

I figured that I can store the date in a property of the exchange, like this:

```
.setProperty("dynamicDate", simple("${body.myDate}"))
```

I'm struggling with using the property to build the address.
What would be the nicer way to replace the harcoded date with the value from the JSON object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using recipientList and the "simple" language, after forcing the exchange patter to InOut (I needed to process the webserver response)

```
.setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
.recipientList( simple("cxfrs://${header.myComputedAddress}"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use (notice the `D` after `to`)

```
.toD("cxfrs:https://myserver.edu/dostuff/${exchangeProperty.dynamicDate}/deals");
```

or

```
.toD("cxfrs:https://myserver.edu/dostuff/${body.myDate}/deals");
```

See http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html for Camel dynamic endpoints.